# How to get the return type of the timed command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the bash builtin `time` to measure how long the execution of a command takes.

The problem is getting the return code from the timed command. After looking into

```
help time
```

it seems that time always return 0 and not the return code of the executed command. Is there some way to get the return status of the timed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked `help time` and it displays help message for `time` and `times`

For `time`

```
Exit Status:
The return status is the return status of PIPELINE.
```

For `times`

```
Exit Status:
Always succeeds.
```

Is it possible that you misread?

Comment: +1 Yes, I just skipped of the help page and read about the `times` exit status :-).

Answer (score 3):

`man time` gives me:

> If the program exited normally, the return value of time is the
>          return value of the program it executed and measured. Otherwise, the return value is 128 plus the number of the signal which
>   caused the program to stop
>          or terminate.

Note there's a shell-builtin `time`, and a `/usr/bin/time`

```
/usr/bin/time false
/usr/bin/time true
```

give me the appropriate (1 and 0) error codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
time lsa
-bash: lsa: command not found

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

echo $?
127

time ls
aa.aa

real    0m0.564s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s

echo $?
0
```

127 if it fails